# How to draw arc on canvas HTML5 without interpolation?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am using the following code to draw on HTML5 canvas:

```
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
```

However, if I print unique values:

```
console.log(new Set(context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data))
```

I can see that the color that I use in `fillStyle` gets interpolated.

I tried to disable interpolation/smoothing by adding the following flags:

```
  context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

However, it does not help. I would highly appreciate if you could advise me how to fix the issue.

Comment: By interpolation do you mean anti-aliasing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing?

Comment: I do not know exactly what is the reason of this blur.. I guess that because the result of drawing arc is in between of pixels, the color gets interpolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is no native way to draw circles that are pixelated. To do that you must render each pixel manually.

There are several methods you can use to do this. The most common have some additional artifacts (like inconsistent line width) that are hard to avoid.

The following function draw a circle using a modification of the [Berzingham line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) (also good for rendering pixelated lines) called the [Midpoint circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm)

Unfortunately most of the methods that can draw arbitrary lines and circle are slow.  The two mentioned above are the fastest standard methods I know about.

### Example

The example defines 3 functions to draw pixelated circles

- `pixelPixelatedCircle`  (Red outer circles and single blue in example) draws a single pixel wide circle using the current fill style
- `fillPixelatedCircle`  (Red inner circle in example) draws a a solid circle using the current fill style
- `strokePixelatedCircle` (Black circles in example) draws a circle line with a width. Not the width only works when it is >= 2. If you want a single pixel width use the first function. Also not that this function uses a second canvas to render the circle

The example draws all three types

The outer red circle drawn using `pixelPixelatedCircle` are to demonstrate that the quality of the circles are consistent. There should be alternating 1 pixel width circles, red and dark red. and an outer blue just touching the canvas edge circles.

For circles less than radius of 2 use `ctx.rect` as the outcome will be the same.

- **Note** the circle radius is an integer thus a circle radius 1000 will be identical to circle radius 1000.9 The sample applies to the circle center. To be able to have sub pixel positioning and radius will need another algorithm which is slower and has lower quality lines.
- **Note** I added a simple zoom canvas so I could see the results better, I was going to remove it but left it in just for interested people. It is not crucial to the answer.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const w = canvas.width;
const h = canvas.height;
const size = Math.min(w, h);
const circleWorkCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const cCtx = circleWorkCanvas.getContext("2d");
function resizeCircleCanvas(ctx) {
    if (circleWorkCanvas.width !== ctx.canvas.width || circleWorkCanvas.height !== ctx.canvas.height) {
        circleWorkCanvas.width = ctx.canvas.width;
        circleWorkCanvas.height = ctx.canvas.height;
    }
}

strokePixelatedCircle(ctx, w / 2 | 0, h / 2 | 0, size * 0.35, 5);
strokePixelatedCircle(ctx, w / 2 | 0, h / 2 | 0, size * 0.3, 4);
strokePixelatedCircle(ctx, w / 2 | 0, h / 2 | 0, size * 0.25, 3);
strokePixelatedCircle(ctx, w / 2 | 0, h / 2 | 0, size * 0.2, 2);


ctx.fillStyle = "red";
fillPixelatedCircle(ctx, w / 2, h / 2, size * 0.15);
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
pixelPixelatedCircle(ctx, w / 2, h / 2, size * 0.38);
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
pixelPixelatedCircle(ctx, w / 2, h / 2, size * 0.5);

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
for(let v = 0.40; v < 0.49; v += 1 / size) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#600"
    pixelPixelatedCircle(ctx, w / 2, h / 2, size * v);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#F00"
    v += 1 / size;
    pixelPixelatedCircle(ctx, w / 2, h / 2, size * v );
}


function strokePixelatedCircle(ctx, cx, cy, r, lineWidth) {
    resizeCircleCanvas(ctx);
    cCtx.clearRect(0, 0, cCtx.canvas.width, cCtx.canvas.height);
    cCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";    
    cCtx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle;
    fillPixelatedCircle(cCtx, cx, cy, r + lineWidth / 2);
    cCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";    
    fillPixelatedCircle(cCtx, cx, cy, r - lineWidth / 2);
    cCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";   
    ctx.drawImage(cCtx.canvas, 0, 0);
}
    

function fillPixelatedCircle(ctx, cx, cy, r){
    r |= 0; // floor radius
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // ensure default transform
    var x = r, y = 0, dx = 1, dy = 1;
    var err = dx - (r << 1);
    var x0 = cx - 1| 0, y0 = cy | 0;
    var lx = x,ly = y;
    ctx.beginPath();
    while (x >= y) {
        ctx.rect(x0 - x, y0 + y, x * 2 + 2, 1);
        ctx.rect(x0 - x, y0 - y, x * 2 + 2, 1);
        if (x !== lx){
            ctx.rect(x0 - ly, y0 - lx, ly * 2 + 2, 1);
            ctx.rect(x0 - ly, y0 + lx, ly * 2 + 2, 1);
        }
        lx = x;
        ly = y;
        y++;
        err += dy;
        dy += 2;
        if (err > 0) {
            x--;
            dx += 2;
            err += (-r << 1) + dx;
        }
    }
    if (x !== lx) {
        ctx.rect(x0 - ly, y0 - lx, ly * 2 + 1, 1);
        ctx.rect(x0 - ly, y0 + lx, ly * 2 + 1, 1);
    }    
    ctx.fill();
}
function pixelPixelatedCircle(ctx, cx, cy, r){
    r |= 0;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // ensure default transform
    var x = r, y = 0, dx = 1, dy = 1;
    var err = dx - (r << 1);
    var x0 = cx | 0, y0 = cy  | 0;
    var lx = x,ly = y;
    var w = 1, px = x0;
    ctx.beginPath();
    var rendering = 2;
    while (rendering) {
        const yy = y0 - y;
        const yy1 = y0 + y - 1;
        const xx = x0 - x;
        const xx1 = x0 + x - 1;
        ctx.rect(xx, yy1, 1, 1);    
        ctx.rect(xx, yy, 1, 1); 
        ctx.rect(xx1, yy1, 1, 1);    
        ctx.rect(xx1, yy, 1, 1);
        if (x !== lx){
            const yy = y0 - lx;
            const yy1 = y0 + lx - 1;
            const xx = x0 - ly;
            w = px - xx;
            const xx1 = x0 + ly - w;
            ctx.rect(xx, yy, w, 1);
            ctx.rect(xx, yy1, w, 1); 
            ctx.rect(xx1, yy, w, 1); 
            ctx.rect(xx1, yy1, w, 1);
            px = xx;
        }
        lx = x;
        ly = y;
        y++;
        err += dy;
        dy += 2;
        if (err > 0) {
            x--;
            dx += 2;
            err += (-r << 1) + dx;
        }
        if (x < y) { rendering -- }
    }
    ctx.fill();
}
const ctxZ = canvasZoom.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",(event) => {
    ctxZ.clearRect(0,0,30,30);
    ctxZ.drawImage(canvas, -(event.pageX-10), -(event.pageY-10));

});
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid black}
#canvasZoom {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvasZoom" width="30" height="30"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot for such a detailed answer!!! I will read through it tomorrow, and after testing, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a built-in setting that I can find, but you can loop through the image data and set the individual pixels if they are within some threshold of what you want.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.arc(250, 250, 250, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
context.fill();
context.closePath();

console.log(getDistinctColors(context).length + " distinct colors before filter");

solidifyColor(context, 255, 0, 0);

console.log(getDistinctColors(context).length + " distinct colors aftrer filter");

function solidifyColor(context, r, g, b, threshold = 3) {
  const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
  for (let i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
    var rDif = Math.abs(imageData.data[i + 0] - r);
    var bDif = Math.abs(imageData.data[i + 1] - b);
    var gDif = Math.abs(imageData.data[i + 2] - g);
    if (rDif <= threshold && bDif <= threshold && gDif <= threshold) {
      imageData.data[i + 0] = r;
      imageData.data[i + 1] = g;
      imageData.data[i + 2] = b;
      imageData.data[i + 3] = 255; // remove alpha
    }
  }
  context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

function getDistinctColors(context) {
  var colors = [];
  const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
  for (let i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
    colors.push([
      imageData.data[i + 0], // R value
      imageData.data[i + 1], // G value
      imageData.data[i + 2], // B value
      imageData.data[i + 3] // A value
    ]);
  }
  return [...new Set(colors.map(a => JSON.stringify(a)))].map(a => JSON.parse(a));
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=500 height=500></canvas>
```